# How to get a CloudBlobDirectory pointing toward the container root?

Tags: azure-storage

With the [WindowsAzure.Storage](http://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage) library, I would like to create a `CloudBlobDirectory` that refers to the root of the container. The method `CloudBlobContainer.GetDirectoryReference(string)` unfortunately fails with an argument exception called with `String.Empty` as argument.

Is-it possible to have a `CloudBlobDirectory` referring to the root of the container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C# SDK, I was able to get it via:

```
cloudBlobContainer.GetDirectoryReference(string.Empty)
```

Nuget: Assembly Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, Version=9.3.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35

Answer (score 1):

for the Java SDK 0.5.0, the following works.

```
container.GetDirectoryReference(container.getURI().toString())
```

hopefully works for other SDKs too.